# How to save an Offer to Google Wallet using JWT?

Tags: android, jwt, android-pay

Actually I want to save an offer to 'Google Wallet'. As I haven't worked on it before I did some RND and came across [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/get-started/implementing-the-api/save-to-google-pay#use-native-android-sdk). In this documentation they are creating Offer class object at Android side but, in my case the Offer class object is creating at our back-end server and I'm getting ready-made JWT token just by hitting one API to our back-end server, now using that JWT token I want to save the offer to the 'Google-Wallet'. Now my question is, is it possible? if Yes please tell me How? Also please let me know if I can provide more details so that you can understand my problem. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

I have been working on this at [PassNinja](http://passninja.com/). The most convenient method for your use case would be to use the JWT link and intent.
Fill in your generated JWT and class ID:
`https://www.android.com/{classid}/savetoandroidpay/{jwt_generated}`

Use an `ACTION_VIEW` intent to open the deep link from the Save to Google Pay button.
Make sure that the button that triggers the intent uses the Brand guidelines.

```
Intent webIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("https://www.android.com/payapp/savetoandroidpay/" + JWT));
context.startActivity(webIntent)`
```

For more info on deep links and Save to Google Pay, [here is a video](http://passninja.com/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please tell me where I'll get the {classid} filed? I tried "https://www.android.com/payapp/savetoandroidpay/" + JWT) this url by replacing my JWT token but, I'm getting "Something wen't wrong. Please try again later" errron on web page.

Comment: Assuming you have already created a Class, you should be able to find it in your Merchant Center. https://wallet.google.com/merchant/walletobjects/admin/accounts/

Comment: Thanks @Scott Condron I'll check and let you know.

Comment: Hi Scott! I tried by replacing my 'class-id' and 'JWT' in below URL 
"https://www.android.com/{classid}/savetoandroidpay/{jwt_generated}"
but, getting "404" error. I checked, the 'class-id' and 'JWT' I'm sending are correct.

Comment: The URL is now `https://pay.google.com/gp/v/save/${jwt}`. You can find more information here : https://developers.google.com/pay/passes/guides/implement-the-api/save-passes-to-google-pay#add-link-to-email

Comment: Is there any way to get a success or error callback to determine if the user has actually saved the pass after launching the Intent?